# ttk.Entry: no caret visible if text is right justified

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

When ttk.Entry['justify']='right' is set the caret cannot be seen when the window shows up.
Hence any user identifies the focused entry widget by seeing the caret, this is very weird.
How can I make the caret visible? 
I tried with styles but it didn't work.
This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('My.TEntry', padding=10)
entry = ttk.Entry(root, style='My.TEntry')
entry['justify'] = 'right'
entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe', padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Can someone help?

EDIT:
1.) I'm using Python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18.04
2.) It's not a matter of focus. I can't see the caret even if the widget has focus.

Comment: I can see the caret just fine after clicking into the entry field. Are you just wanting the focus to default to the entry field? Try adding `entry.focus()` just before your mainloop and let me know if that helped. If that does not help what OS/Version are you on?

Comment: @Mike: really? I can't see it. I'm using Python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It may be an an issue with how Ubuntu displays widgets. On windows this is not an issue. I currently do not have a linux dustro to test on. Hopefully someone else will.

Comment: I see the caret just fine on OSX, too.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this could help you, simply do entry.focus():

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('My.TEntry', padding=10)
entry = ttk.Entry(root, style='My.TEntry')
entry['justify'] = 'right'
entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe', padx=5, pady=5)
entry.focus()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: no, it's not a matter of focus. That's the problem: even when the widget has focus nobody will recognize it because the caret cannot be seen.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood you then. I will remove my answer as it is not a solution nor a partial solution to the problem.